# SystemError when sharing a gensim (numpy) model in multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, gensim, word2vec

I have many independent tasks that read *but not write to* the same gensim model which is about 3.6GB in size. (Gensim is a topic modelling library built upon numpy.) So I decide to parallelize them by first loading the gensim model from a file:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from multiprocessing import Pool
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

And then pass the `model` as a parameter to a pool of processes to run `doWork`:

```
def doWork(experiment, doc):
  print "Begin working"
  # do some work here; access model by experiment.model

class Experiment(object):
   def __init__(self, model, docs):
     self.model = model
     self.docs = docs
   def run(self):
     pool = Pool(processes = 4)
     print "Done preparing"
     results = pool.map(doWork, [(self, doc) for doc in self.docs])
     return results

experiment = Experiment(model, ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt'])
experiment.run()
```

When I ran this script (the two segments I show here are a runnable script; please copy), it got stuck on the `pool.map` line and a `SystemError` occurred. The output was:

```
Done preparing
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

The error had never occurred before I introduced gensim to my program. (Gensim without multiprocessing also works for me.) I think it may be related to the interoperation with C code underlying gensim and numpy (BLAS). **I wanted to know the reason of this error and how to fix it.** If I can't use gensim with subprocessing, what are the alternatives?

I don't think the `model` would be copied, because my OS (Mac OS X) should be using the copy-on-write strategy. I don't think it is related to memory synchronization either, because not a line of "Begin working" is printed, i.e. the `model` has not been accessed by my code. The error is in passing the `model` to the sub-processes.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058706/python-systemerror-null-result-without-error-in-pyobject-call ?

Comment: @boardrider You're probably right. Just that in this case I didn't write the C code myself -- it's part of a library. I'm not able to locate the problem because I don't know which lines of C code are executed when starting subprocessing (in my opinion, none, but that cannot explain the problem).